# I keep getting the error message"Error in eff_weights[i, ] <- eff.port$pw : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r

I am new to R and really need some help. I keep getting the error message

> "Error in eff_weights[i, ] <- eff.port$pw :    number of items to
>   replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

when I run the loop. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank you so much in advance!

```
 # Create for loop to find efficient frontier

for (i in 1 : length(grid)) {
   eff.port <- portfolio.optim(returns, pm = grid[i], shorts =TRUE)
   vector_pm[i] <- eff.port$pm
   vector_psd[i] <- eff.port$ps
   eff_weights[i, ] <- eff.port$pw
}
```

Comment: Please, try to create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a sample of your data or dummy data to reproduce the problem it is hard to provide a certain solution. However, in your loop you assign a vector of values from a column, `eff.port$pw`, to the ith row of a dataframe or matrix, `eff_weights[i, ]`. The error message is saying the are different lengths - use the `length()` or `dim()` functions to compare the lengths of these two. Your vector `eff.port$pw` and row `eff_weight[i,]` must be the same length.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at this.  This is what I am gerneating for eff_port$pw
[1]  2.2342660 -0.2146492 -0.1278270  0.2958349 -0.9179933 -0.3243578 -0.2562219
[8]  0.3109482

Comment: Could you do `dim(eff_port$pw)` and `dim(eff_weight[1,])` and post the results as a comment here please

Comment: For  <dim(eff_port$pw)
NULL.For > dim(eff_weight[1, ])
Error: object 'eff_weight' not found. I have the following assigned to eff_weight. eff_weights <- matrix(NA, 60, 30)

Comment: I was able to get it to work! I just needed to change the 30 to an 8 and it ran perfect. thank you for your help!

Comment: As it solved your problem you should accept the answer